# Bar graph plot with values on top python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I have a table in my pandas df.

```
    Total_orders    frequency
      0.0           18679137
      1.0           360235
      2.0           68214
      3.0           20512
      4.0           7211
      ...           ...
      50.0          12
```

I want to plot a bar graph total orders vs frequency, with the values of frequency displayed on the top of each bars.

I am running these three codes.

Code1:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
df2 = df.groupby('Total_orders')['frequency'].plot(kind='bar')
plt.xlabel('Total_orders')
plt.ylabel('frequency')

for rect in df2.patches:
    height = rect.get_height()
    df2.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height+100,
'%d' % int(height),ha='center', va='bottom', rotation=90)
```

Code2:(for loop)

```
for ii,rect in enumerate(df2.patches):
    height = rect.get_height()
    df2.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.14*height+100,'%d' % int(height),ha='center', va='bottom', rotation=90)
```

Code3

```
for p in df2.patches:
df2.annotate(str(p.get_height()), (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() *1.05),rotation=90)
```

but when I am running the code it's showing me error, that

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'patches'

Any idea why this is happening, and how to remove it?

Comment: Looks like you're accessing a `Series` object (`df2`?) and trying to iterate its `patches`, but a `Series` object doesn't have a `patches` attribute. You'll have to find a way to access whatever object has the `patches` you want to iterate.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def autolabel(rects, height_factor=1.05):
    # attach some text labels
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., height_factor*height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')


In [48]: df
Out[48]:
   Total_orders  frequency
0           0.0   18679137
1           1.0     360235
2           2.0      68214
3           3.0      20512
4           4.0       7211
5          50.0         12

In [49]: import matplotlib

In [50]: matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

In [51]: ax = df.plot.bar(x='Total_orders', y='frequency', rot=0, width=0.85, alpha=0.6, figsize=(14,12))

In [52]: autolabel(ax.patches, 1.02)
```

[image]

Comment: can i increase the height of the values, i mean it's very close to x axis as shown in figure., i want it a little up(approx 0.5cm) so that my plot looks nice.

Comment: @SRingne, sure just set `height_factor` parameter bit higher

Comment: diid that ,increased it further till 5, also did `height_factor*height+100` but no change